# NameError truncates model name

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I seem to have an issue with Rails conventions (I think).  I have the following classes that give me a NameError and the error looks like 
    'uninitialized constant Store::Campu' (I didn't misspell Campus it shows up like this in the error page)

### Models

```
Store (store.rb)
 has_many :campus

Campus (campus.rb)
  belongs_to :store
```

To display all stores at the index page I have the following index action which works fine.

```
def index
  @stores = Store.all
end
```

Then to allow the user to do something like navigate to a create file page.

```
def create_import_file
  @stores = Store.find_by params[:id]
  render 'create_file'

end
```

I have no idea what I a missing with this error. Thanks for looking any help you can provide.

## **Update**

```
 Store (store.rb)
   has_many :campuses
  validates :store_id, presence: true, uniqueness: true, numericality: { only_integer: true } (adding this for good measure. This is everything from my model classes so far)
Campus (campus.rb)
  self.table_name = "campuses" (Note: I couldn't get this to work without adding this entry.)
  belongs_to :store
```

I have two tables so far. stores & campuses The columns are like so:

### Tables

```
stores
  + id
  + store_id
  + created_at
  + updated_at
campuses
  + id
  + campus_id
  + campus_name
  + created_at
  + updated_at
```

## Solution

#### That worked for me

Turns out that Rails had issues with pluralizing "campus". Being new I had no idea what was going on. Adding a line to my config/initializers/inflections.rb fixed this.

Using this now everything can just be named 'campus'.

```
ActiveSupport::Inflector.inflections(:en) do |inflect|   
  inflect.uncountable "campus"
end
```

Comment: Did you generated Campus model with `rails g model Campus` right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use `plural` form here

```
Store (store.rb)
has_many :campus
```

should be

```
Store (store.rb)
has_many :campuses # here
```

Comment: I ran the "campus".tableize and it gave me "campus" back. Even though I get campus as the plural I should still uses has_many :campuses?

Comment: @Carl Where you ran `campus.tableize`?

Comment: @Carl It really gave you `campus` as a result? It shouldn't be.

Comment: I ran "campus".tableize in the rails console and it gives "campus". I'll have to go back and modify my migrations as well. Thanks for the help!

Comment: I still seem to get the same behaviour. I changed the table to 'campuses'. I also set the self.table_name = 'campuses' in the campus model. But, every time I try to call store.campuses I get an error. NameError: uninitialized constant Store::Campuse
Any idea what I am doing wrong?

Comment: @Carl update your question with exact mode in models and their filenams

Comment: Sorry, I am a bit new to Rails. What do you mean by mode in models?

Comment: @Carl let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/52698/discussion-between-pavan-and-carl)